# Calling Method in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When calling a method, I use

```
[self methodname];
```

The problem I'm having is, in `xCode` I get loads of warnings! It's saying `"*xxxappdelegate.app may not respond to methodname*"`.

Is there a better way to call methods?

Comment: I wouldn't *always* use `self`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get that warning, that means either:

- That method does not exist in your
  class
- If you are calling that method
  on a different class (not self) then
  you have not imported the headers for
  that class

Comment: Thanks,

Ill take a look at my .h file again :)

Answer (score 4):

These warnings just mean that the compiler does not know if the class in question has the method you are calling. Make sure the method you're calling is defined above the place in the .m file you are using it in, or declare the method at the top of the file.

```
@implemention A

-(void)blah
{
    [self foo]; // warning!
}

-(void)foo
{
    [self blah]; // no warning
}

@end
```

Comment: to avoid this, declare the method in .h file.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called compiling order. When you call method `foo` it is not defined yet, however when you call method `blah` it is defined just in the upper line.

Much more specific:

```
cout << a;
string a = "hello";
```

When you do that you will get an error *undefined variable "a"*. What you should do is:

```
string a = "hello";
cout << a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `methodname` to the `@interface` for the class, xxxappdelegate in your example.  Or just make sure the `methodname` implementation is before the place you call it in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the .h file has the method declared there can be some issue related to xcodes inability to index to solve this go to preferences and delete archives and other stored data.